# passing data from controller to view in CodeIgniter results in Undefined variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, runtime-error

I have this function in my controller:

```
public function checkout(){
        $data['items'] = $this->cart_model->get_items();

        $this->load->view("templates/header");
        $this->load->view("cart/checkout", $data['items']);
    }
```

Inside the checkout view I try to use this variable:

```
<?php foreach($items as $k => $item){?>
```

But this results in an error:

Message: Undefined variable: items

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure data['items'] is populated with the expected results.  In your checkout try var_dump(data['items'])

Comment: Hi Sebastian, don't inject `$data['items']`, just use `$this->load->view("cart/checkout", $data);`, then on your view file, use `$items`, or as you would do normally, `foreach ($items as $item) { // code here }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
$this->load->view("cart/checkout", $data['items']);
```

to this

```
$this->load->view("cart/checkout", $data);
```